# jQuery UI Dialog and gif + text display

Tags: jquery-ui-dialog

What is proper way to display a gif image into the dialog with text with nice formatting etc..
So far here is my code:
Copy code

```
var $dialog = jQuery('<div></div>').html('<p>Sending your message...</p><img src="../images/AjaxWait.gif"/>')
```

however by doing this the gif is not aligned nicely to the text, etc
What is the best way to format content of the dialog?
thanks
bogumbiker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use CSS, what are you looking for as the end result.

Something like this I would float my image left

```
var $dialog = jQuery('<div></div>').html('<p>Sending your message...</p><img src="../images/AjaxWait.gif" style="float: left; padding: 10px;"/>')
```

Comment: I believe the paragraph needs to be floated, not the image.

Comment: depends on what you want it to look like. I assume this is an animated gif, so I prefer the gif to spin to the left of the text.

Comment: Thanks! So the: 
    "stylefloat: left; padding: 10px;"
will only style image? Or both <P> and <img> tags?
thanks

Comment: It will move the image to the left and put a little space around it so that the image is not right up next to the text.

Comment: Better is using the gif element as background of holder. Set it in css without repeating.

Answer (score 1):

Float the paragraph to the left with CSS.